# Can someone give me an example of regular expressions using {x} and {x,y}?

Tags: ruby, regex

I just learned from a book about regular expressions in the Ruby language. I did Google it, but still got confused about `{x}` and `{x,y}`.

The book says:

> {x}→Match x occurrences of the preceding character.
>   {x,y}→Match at least x occurrences and at most y occurrences.

Can anyone explain this better, or provide some examples?

Comment: '.. the preceding *character*' is not entirely true. I would suggest 'the preceding *expression*', because this also works with grouped objects: /(test){3,5}/ and other constructions: /[[:ascii:]]{,10}/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, look at these examples:

http://rubular.com/r/sARHv0vf72

http://rubular.com/r/730Zo6rIls

```
/a{4}/
```

is the short version for:

```
/aaaa/
```

It says: Match exact 4 (consecutive) characters of 'a'.

where

```
/a{2,4}/
```

says: Match at least 2, and at most 4 characters of 'a'.

it will match

```
/aa/
/aaa/
/aaaa/
```

and it won't match

```
/a/
/aaaaa/
/xxx/
```

Comment: This answer has been added to the [Stack Overflow Regular Expression FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496), under "Quantifiers".

Answer (score 1):

[`Limiting Repetition`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) good online tutorial for this.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend [regexbuddy.com](http://regexbuddy.com) and very briefly, the regex below does what you refer to:

```
[0-9]{3}|\w{3}
```

The [ ] characters indicate that you must match a number between 0 and 9. It can be anything, but the [ ] is literal match. The { } with a 3 inside means match sets of 3 numbers between 0 and 9. The | is an or statement. The \w, is short hand for any word character and once again the {3} returns only sets of 3.

If you go to [RegexPal.com](http://regexpal.com) you can enter the code above and test it. I used the following data to test the expression:

```
909 steve kinzey
```

and the expression matched the 909, the 'ste', the 'kin' and the 'zey'. It did not match the 've' because it is only 2 word characters long and a word character does not span white space so it could not carry over to the second word.

Answer (score 1):

### Interval Expressions

GNU awk refers to these as "interval expressions" in the [Regexp Operators](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp-Operators.html) section of its manual. It explains the expressions as follows:

> {n}
>   {n,}
>   {n,m}
>   One or two numbers inside braces denote an interval expression. If there is one number in the braces, the preceding regexp is repeated n times. If there are two numbers separated by a comma, the preceding regexp is repeated n to m times. If there is one number followed by a comma, then the preceding regexp is repeated at least n times:

The manual also includes these reference examples:

```
wh{3}y
    Matches ‘whhhy’, but not ‘why’ or ‘whhhhy’.
wh{3,5}y
    Matches ‘whhhy’, ‘whhhhy’, or ‘whhhhhy’, only.
wh{2,}y
    Matches ‘whhy’ or ‘whhhy’, and so on.
```

### See Also

- Ruby's [Regexp](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html) class.
- Quantifiers section of Ruby's [oniguruma](http://oniguruma.rubyforge.org/oniguruma/) engine.